# How can one perform the equivalent Microsoft Graph Query using the SDK in C#?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, odata, microsoft-graph-sdks

Given a group ID, I wish to retrieve the DisplayName (only) for the group.  Using the online Microsoft Graph Explorer, I can do this.

I want to do it from an application in C#.  The problem is that there seems to be no way of specifying the `$select` parameter (highlighted), since the call `graphServiceClient.Groups.GetByIds` uses POST, and no arguments to `PostAsync` allow the specification of query parameters.

Is this even possible?  It seems like it should work since the call succeeds from the Microsoft Graph Explorer.

What I have tried:

```
var groups = await graphServiceClient.Groups.GetByIds
    .PostAsync(new() { Ids = ids, Types = new() { "group" } }, null, cancellationToken)
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
return groups?.Value?.Select(d => ((Microsoft.Graph.Models.Group)d).DisplayName);
```

works in that it gets ALL the properties including `DisplayName`.  I want to get just `DisplayName`.

[image: Microsoft Graph Query using Graph Explorer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an issue in SDK. Could you please report the issue here:

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues

As a workaround you can modify query parameters of a request before the request is sent.

```
var requestInformation = graphClient.DirectoryObjects
    .GetByIds
    .ToPostRequestInformation(new() 
        { 
            Ids = ids, 
            Types = new() { "group" } 
        });
requestInformation.QueryParameters["%24select"] = new[] { "displayName" };
requestInformation.UrlTemplate += "{?%24select}";
var result = await graphClient
    .RequestAdapter
    .SendAsync<GetByIdsResponse>(requestInformation, GetByIdsResponse.CreateFromDiscriminatorValue);
```

Comment: Thank you, that works as desired.  I suspect you missed out a '4' in your requestInformation.UrlTemplate "{?%24select}"

I have opened an issue as well: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/2206